# Why I can't get access to action(Spring Security plugin)

Tags: grails-plugin, grails-2.3

I create controlller security and action rights().

```
class SecurityController {
    static defaultAction = "rights"
def rights() {
    new Requestmap(url:"/user/enterPage/**", configAttribute: "permitAll").save(flush: true)
    render "Success"
}
```

After I write this url:"/security/rights" in browser. All good, but after  I write this url:"/user/enterPage", then I can't get access. Why? How to fix this?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After created Reqestmap. Need perform full reload of Requestmap cache. for it need use `clearCachedRequestmaps()`

From springSecurityService

For example:

```
 def request= new Requestmap(url:"/user/enterPage/**", configAttribute: "permitAll").save(flush: true)
   springSecurityService.clearCachedRequestmaps()
```

Sorry for my English :)